# emgucv c# OpenCv:u!=0 error at 1920*1080p

Tags: c#, emgucv

I can get IP camera live video stream at 960*540p resolution using emgucv in c#. But when I changed camera stream resolution to 1920*1080p, 
I am getting this error:

> OpenCv:u!=0 error

I am gettin the error at this line:

```
_capture.Retrieve(frame, 0);
```

Below is my code :

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        try
        {
            _capture = new VideoCapture("rtsp://root:camera@192.168.3.232/stream/profile1=u");
            _capture.ImageGrabbed += ProcessFrame;

        }
    }

    private void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs arg)
    {
        Mat frame = new Mat();
        _capture.Retrieve(frame, 0);
        ımageBox1.Image = frame;

    }
```

I searched this questions but no solution.

[OpenCv:u!=0 Exception while reading frames from video file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41612852/opencvu-0-exception-while-reading-frames-from-video-file)

[C# EmguCV error "OpenCV: u != 0"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46551150/c-sharp-emgucv-error-opencv-u-0?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)